# Lightbox2 with CCK fields, duplicate images in articles

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm having some trouble with [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) for Drupal 7, or rather I don't know how to configure it properly. In my [desperate search](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18219/image-and-other-media-file-management) for a tool that will handle inserting scaled image thumbnails with links to original images into random places of article text I came over Lightbox2 that does pretty much what I need. I've created a field_image for my article type, then went to Manage Display, discovered a helluva lot of Lightbox Formats available for field_image and happily set it to Medium -> Original (that was what I needed all the way long). I proceeded with creating an article, adding a picture to it and writing something like this in article body:

```
Much text here
<a href="/sites/default/files/articles/image.jpg" rel='lightbox[][My image]'><img src="/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/articles/image.jpg"></a>
Even more text here.
```

I've got what I wanted and there was a pic sitting between the two paragraphs of text. But there also was the same pic right under the article text. I tried to counter it by setting field_image Format in Manage Display to "Hidden". It hid the bottom pic, yes. But with "Hidden" setting active my further uploaded images are no longer processed by Drupal to make medium-sized previews of them (Drupal must think I don't need them because I set his precious field_image to "Hidden"). Setting it to something meaningful every time I want to add an image to an article and then turn it off to prevent additional images from showing seems too great a pain. How does one handle that?

Comment: Did you field_image to hidden in Manage Fields or Manage Display tab?

Comment: @rocketeerbkw , it was Manage Display. My bad. I've corrected the initial post.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I tested the same steps but after hiding the image field in `Manage Display` it still generates thumbnails correctly. The functions that generate thumbnails don't know anything about your content type, just the path to the image it needs to process.

Comment: @rocketeerbkw , I do. And what's more annoying, I tried to disable and then re-enable Lightbox2 and now there are no Lightbox2 formats for field_image to choose from. Must've configured it wrong again... As for now I set Format to Medium for field_image in Manage Display and define .field-name-field-image class in my site's theme CSS and set it to display:none. Drupal still generates its IMG tags for field_image under article body though, I merely make these images invisible but they are loaded by user's browser regardless of their visibility. The whole output look like this:

Comment: `Article text
<img scr="image.jpg"><!--manually written HTML-->
More article text

<div class="field-name-field-image"><img scr="image.jpg"></div><!--HTML generated by Drupal-->`

I thought that loading invisible images won't hurt performance in my case because I'm going to show these pictures anyway, only just in one place instead of two.